# output error: different outputs on two different compilers: Prime Cryptarithm USACO

Tags: c++

The following cryptarithm is a multiplication problem that can be solved by substituting digits from a specified set of N digits into the positions marked with *. If the set of prime digits {2,3,5,7} is selected, the cryptarithm is called a PRIME CRYPTARITHM. Example:

```
      * * *
     x  * *
    -------
      * * *         <-- partial product 1
    * * *           <-- partial product 2
    -------
    * * * *
```

These stars can be replaced only by a defined set of integers N which is given by the USACO grader.
**The partial products must be three digits long.**

Data given:

```
4       /* <-- This is the given size of set N from which the multiplicand and multiplier is taken */
2 3 5 7 /* <-- Set N */
```

The task is to calculate the number of possible outcomes and output the number.

My question:
In my compiler,The output is 0,which is correct,but in the USACO grader my program outputs 1. I am not able to identify what the problem is. 
Could someone help me resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

MY PROGRAM CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int *sortInput(int arrSetN[], int numofDigs)
{
    for(int ictr=0;ictr<numofDigs;ictr++)
    {
        for(int jctr=ictr+1;jctr<numofDigs;jctr++)
        {
            if(arrSetN[ictr]>arrSetN[jctr])
            {
                swap(arrSetN[ictr],arrSetN[jctr]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrSetN;
}
bool checkNum(int num,int arrSetN[],int numofDigs)
{
    int countDigits=0,tempNum=num,ictr=0,jctr=0;
    int *arrDigits,*digitTally;

    /*
    Counting the number of digits in num.    
    */
    for(;tempNum>0;)
    {
        tempNum=tempNum/10;
        countDigits++;
    }
    arrDigits=new int[countDigits];
    digitTally=new int[countDigits];

    /*
        making digitTally = 0
    */
    for(ictr=0;ictr<countDigits;ictr++)
        digitTally[ictr]=0;

    /*
        retrieving the digits of num.
    */
    for(ictr=0;ictr<countDigits;ictr++)
    {
        arrDigits[ictr]=num%10;
        num=num/10;
    }

    /*
        checking if all digits of num are part of set N.
    */
    for(ictr=0;ictr<countDigits;ictr++)
    {
        for(jctr=0;jctr<=numofDigs;jctr++)
        {
            if(arrDigits[ictr]==arrSetN[jctr])
                digitTally[ictr]=1;
        }
    }

    for(int cfc=0;cfc<countDigits;cfc++)
    {
        if(digitTally[cfc]==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("crypt1.out");
    ifstream fin("crypt1.in");
    int numofDigs,ictr=0,a,b,c,d, e,p1,p2,sum,p2test;
    int actr=0,bctr=0,cctr=0,dctr=0,ectr=0,tally=0;
    bool sumCheck,p1Check,p2Check;
    fin>>numofDigs;
    int *arrSetN;
    arrSetN = new int[numofDigs];
    for(ictr=0;ictr<numofDigs;ictr++)
    {
        fin>>arrSetN[ictr];
    }
    arrSetN=sortInput(arrSetN,numofDigs);
    for(actr=0;actr<numofDigs;actr++)
    {
        a=arrSetN[actr];
        for(bctr=0;bctr<numofDigs;bctr++)
        {
            b=arrSetN[bctr];
            for(cctr=0;cctr<numofDigs;cctr++)
            {
                c=arrSetN[cctr];
                for(dctr=0;dctr<numofDigs;dctr++)
                {
                    d=arrSetN[dctr];
                    for(ectr=0;ectr<numofDigs;ectr++)
                    {
                        e=arrSetN[ectr];
                        p1=((a*100)+(b*10)+c)*e;
                        p2=((a*1000)+(b*100)+(c*10))*d;
                        p2test=((a*100)+(b*10)+c)*d;
                        p1Check=checkNum(p1,arrSetN,numofDigs);
                        p2Check=checkNum(p2test,arrSetN,numofDigs);
                        if(p1>999 || p2test>999 || p1<100 || p2test<100)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        sum=p1+p2;
                        sumCheck=checkNum(sum,arrSetN,numofDigs);
                        if(sumCheck==true && p1Check==true && p2Check==true)
                        {
                            tally++;
                            //fout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d<<" "<<e;
                            //fout<<"\t"<<p1<<" "<<p2<<" "<<sum<<"\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fout<<tally<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when the results of a program are different with different compilers, that usually means somewhere in your program you are running into Undefined Behavior.

In your case, the comparison of `j<=numofDigs` in checkNum is incorrect.  You are accessing past the end of arrSetN when `j==numofDigs`.  Since this is undefined, you can get different results.

There may be other similar places, but this is the one I noticed.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks!